# Can I login at login.salesforce.com when MyDomain SAML is broken?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I'm setting up Single Sign On using SAML 2 on Salesforce, and had it working fine, and am forcing users to login at the Identity Provider.

But I made a mistake and changed my SAML to using "Just in Time Provisioning", and now I can't login anymore, as my IdP isn't configured for it. And unfortunately, I also configured it so logging in via my IdP was the only way users can login, so now it appears that I'm effectively locked out!

How can I login to my domain? Is the only way to do so is to get my IdP's assertion correctly setup now to work with JIT provisioning? Is there an url I can use to login at "login.salesforce.com", even though I've explicitely dissallowed this in my "My Domain" config?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! Turns out I could just to to

https://login.salesforce.com

and use the "Forgot Password" link to reset my password. It sent me an email that let me change my password, and logged me in directly to Salesforce after I changed it.

Then I just went to my "My Domain" settings, and disabled "Force login via IDP"